# White space at the bottom of html page when view is changed to fullscreen mode

Tags: css

When I am trying to view the html page in full screen ppt mode(F11), it leaves a white space at the bottom of the page. The height of the image does not get changed accordingly. Although while trying it in normal display mode, its working fine.

Comment: People will need to see an example of what you're talking about, preferably a link and the code you are using that is giving you the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

If this doesn't work please show an example of what you are trying to accomplish. That way people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The document body by default has a margin, remove it using the following css code.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```